# Crank type for an old peugot

Tags: crankset

I'm renovating an old Peugot and need to replace the crank. It takes a clotted crank however I'm not sure on the size. I brought a crank previously and it didn't fit, I couldn't get it on the bike because it didn't slip on.

The amount of teeth required I'm ok with, more concerned with getting the crank on the bike.

Photo attached

[image]

Comment: Rather than quote Sheldon Brown word for word I suggest you check out his articles pertaining to French bike upgrade, refit issues. The article may help you clarify exactly what issues your having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy solution is to rip out the old bottom bracket, put on a modern JIS/ISO bottom bracket. Velo Orange makes some with [french threading](http://store.velo-orange.com/index.php/components/bottom-brackets/grand-cru-bottom-brackets-hollow-axle-alloy-cups-61.html) and [threadless](http://store.velo-orange.com/index.php/components/bottom-brackets/grand-cru-threadless-bottom-brackets.html) (if the threads are stuffed).

Then find your favorite square taper crankset and put it on.

Keeping cottered cranks is extra work since the "right way" to do things with cottered cranks requires a bunch of tools nobody has anymore.

Comment: Definitely recommend swapping out the bottom bracket. It will open up many options (if you don't care about period perfect restoration).  It's going to be much harder to find and install a set of cottered cranks, and replacement parts will be much harder to find since chain ring standards are radically different now (and chainrings are considered consumable parts).  Velo Orange has the bottom bracket to retrofit your (likely french threaded bb) and cranks that look nice and vintage inspired.